# QGIS - layers disappear after loading pre-saved style

Tags: qgis

First time here, I hope I'm doing it right and I hope I'm allowed to ask this here.

I'm making buffer layers out of points in QGIS 3.8.1 Zanzibar, it's 5 point layers and I need to generate the 5 corresponding buffers. They come out alright, but after I load a previously saved style for the layers the geometries simply disappear.

I have:

- Ticked layer off and on, still gone.
- Deactivated any other layer and make sure it's not hidden behind something else.
- Zoomed to layer, not the problem, it zooms where they should be, they're just not visible
- Checked for SRC, it's all good, all of them are the same.
- Open attribute table, all the data is there and it's correct.
- Left click on layer/layer visibility and made sure it is unchecked as it should, I also tried checking it to no avail.
- Made the layers all over again, same result.
- Went to Properties/Source/Query Builder and wrote this (I saw this in a vid where it worked):

```
"FIELD" LIKE "FIELD"
```

Where "FIELD" is a field of my attribute table, tested it correctly and applied...didn't work either.

Just one seemed to come out alright before doing all this, but I followed the exact same procedure for all of them.

Any ideas? Do I have to re-do the style all over again manually for every layer?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I just found out what was wrong, I hope this helps someone in the future:

The style I saved was classifying data based on a particular column, wich of course, must exist and have the exact same name in the other layers in order to work. I just forgot to generate said column on the rest of the layers.

Cheers and thanks  to the editor.